# Spring Roo Birt Integration Web.xml Configuration Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml, spring-roo, birt

I have spring Roo app and i m trying to add birt environment in it.I am following this: https://spring.io/blog/2012/01/30/spring-framework-birt#birtviewer

The problem occurs when i am trying to add birt configuration class in web.xml. Here is the scenario:
1) I have `webmvc-config.xml`,`application-context.xml` which i need to add under `contextConfigLocation`.
2) I have another configuration class `BirtWebConfiguration` which i want to add in web.xml to load at startup.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <display-name>BirtRooDemo2</display-name>

    <description>Roo generated BirtRooDemo2 application</description>

    <!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BirtRooDemo2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param> 

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml,com/palak/org/eclipse/birt/spring/example/BirtWebConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BirtRooDemo2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/uncaughtException</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

How do i manage it? Help please. Thnx.

Comment: what is the error message and stack trace?

Comment: That problem was solved,But now i got new problem. There is some class called applicationConversionService, this is configured under webmvc-config.xml, by this line. <mvc:annotation-driven  conversion-service="applicationConversionService"/>.Now this line needs to be removed if i want to run birt.But if i remove, data cant be converted.so i cant view my data.How to handle it?

Comment: If i keep that line, i got this error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6d2f7005 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager

Comment: @PalakDarji if you solved the issue for this question, as courtesy you should post your solution as an answer. This will allow others with the same issue to use your solution.  If you have a new question you should post it a a completely new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i was able to manage:
My web.xml remains same as it should be ( default configured by roo)

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <display-name>BirtRooDemo2</display-name>

    <description>Roo generated BirtRooDemo2 application</description>

    <!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BirtRooDemo2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BirtRooDemo2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/uncaughtException</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

The problem was with my extra configuration java class, which i have added into `applicationContext.xml` just by defining new bean definition

```
<bean class="com.palak.org.eclipse.birt.spring.example.BirtWebConfiguration" id="birtWebConfiguration"></bean>
```

Plus, i needed to remove this from my webmvc-config.xml :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```